# How to get all previously connected Wi-Fi networks in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, wifi, ios9

I know it's not possible to get all available Wi-Fi networks and it's possible to get the information of current connected Wi-Fi network, correct me if I'm wrong.
I just want to know the feasibility of getting the information of all previously connected Wi-Fi networks, Please help me by sharing your experience.

FYI,
I'm using the following code get current connected Wi-Fi network's info and it's working fine.

```
var currentSSID: String!
let interfaces:CFArray! = CNCopySupportedInterfaces()
for i in 0..<CFArrayGetCount(interfaces) {
    let interfaceName: UnsafePointer<Void>
    =  CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(interfaces, i)
    let rec = unsafeBitCast(interfaceName, AnyObject.self)
    let unsafeInterfaceData = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo("\(rec)")
    if unsafeInterfaceData != nil {
        let interfaceData = unsafeInterfaceData! as Dictionary!
        currentSSID = interfaceData["SSID"] as! String
    } else {
        currentSSID = ""
    }
    print(currentSSID)
}
```

Comment: Hello you never accepted my answer can I know why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a stock iPhone this is not possible from the settings. The information that you want is stored in the iPhone's keychain. If you have access to the iPhone SDK you can start messing around if you like, but I will leave it at that since that would be a StackOverflow answer. [Source](https://superuser.com/questions/62366/how-can-i-find-out-what-wifi-networks-my-iphone-knows-about)

If you have ICloud Keychain enabled, it is possible to fetch this data. Otherwise, you can't. [Source](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/168513/is-it-possible-to-access-a-list-of-wifi-networks-my-iphone-has-used) You can  use [kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess) or do it yourself. [Here is homemade code to save and retrieve keychain values.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30719638/save-and-retrieve-value-via-keychain)
It is a simple swift wrapper for Keychain that works on iOS and OS X

Comment: "iCloud Keychain": I think this approach is possible only in jailbroken iOS devices?.  

"kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess": It's about saving & retrieving the passwords from the app. How is it possible to access saved Wi-Fi networks' list in iOS Settings using this?