# kSecAttrAccount and kSecAttrGeneric

Tags: ios, swift, security, keychain

I would like to save within an account marta@domain.com two values. Example of the dictionaries:

- **Value 1.**

kSecAttrAccount = marta@domain.com

kSecAttrGeneric = value1Key

kSecValueData = value1

- **Value 2.**

kSecAttrAccount = marta@domain.com

kSecAttrGeneric = value2Key

kSecValueData = value2

---

Is it possible? I'm getting an error to do the query when I try to keep the second value.

I attach a snippet of my code:

```
func addCredentials(_ credentials: KeychainCredentials) throws {

let account = credentials.account
let password = credentials.password.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
let generic = credentials.generic

 let accessControl = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(kCFAllocatorDefault, 
            kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly,
            .userPresence,
            nil) 

 // Build the query
 let query: [String: Any] = [kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword,
                                    kSecAttrService as String: serviceName,
                                    kSecAttrAccount as String: account,
                                    kSecAttrGeneric as String: generic,
                                    kSecAttrAccessControl as String: accessControl as Any,
                                    kSecValueData as String: password]

let status = SecItemAdd(query as CFDictionary, nil)
guard status == errSecSuccess else { throw KeychainError(status: status) }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `kSecClassGenericPassword`, the combination of service and account must be unique. For the list of which attributes are part of the primary key, see the documentation for [errSecDuplicateItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/errsecduplicateitem).

> The system considers an item to be a duplicate for a given keychain when that keychain already has an item of the same class with the same set of composite primary keys. Each class of keychain item has a different set of primary keys, although a few attributes are used in common across all classes. In particular, where applicable, kSecAttrSynchronizable and kSecAttrAccessGroup are part of the set of primary keys. The additional per-class primary keys are listed below:
>
> For generic passwords, the primary keys include kSecAttrAccount and kSecAttrService.
>
> For internet passwords, the primary keys include kSecAttrAccount, kSecAttrSecurityDomain, kSecAttrServer, kSecAttrProtocol, kSecAttrAuthenticationType, kSecAttrPort, and kSecAttrPath.
>
> For certificates, the primary keys include kSecAttrCertificateType, kSecAttrIssuer, and kSecAttrSerialNumber.
>
> For key items, the primary keys include kSecAttrKeyClass, kSecAttrKeyType, kSecAttrApplicationLabel, kSecAttrApplicationTag, kSecAttrKeySizeInBits, and kSecAttrEffectiveKeySize.
>
> For identity items, which are a certificate and a private key bundled together, the primary keys are the same as for a certificate. Because a private key may be certified more than once, the uniqueness of the certificate determines that of the identity.

If I were building this, I would likely put all the key/values into a dictionary, and serialize that to a single kSecAttrAccount record.

Alternately, you could merge your account and service values together into the account (if you have a service), and put `value1Key` in the service attribute. Then account+service would be unique to a given key.

Comment: Thank you so much, Rob (:
I'm gonna develop the first option, a dictionary with all the key/values.